# How to catch createReadStream error in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, unzip

It's been 3 days struggling to catch an error in `fs.createReadStream`. There is a file when I try to unzip it it stuck while extracting and doesn't throw any error. Below is my code for reference:

```
const unzip = require("unzip-stream"),
function extractFileAndParse(file) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let extractedDirName = file.replace(".zip", "");
    let unzipPipe = unzip.Extract({
      path: `./directory/${extractedDirName}`,
    });
    try {
      let stream = fs.createReadStream(`${directory}/${file}`).pipe(unzipPipe);
      stream.on("finish", function () {
        return resolve({
          contentid: extractedDirName,
        });
      });
      stream.on("error", (err) => {
        return reject();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error occurred while parsing the file: ", error);
      reject();
    }
  });
}
```

For a normal file, once the extraction is done it goes to `finish` event and return the resolve(). But couldn't catch an error if it get stuck (or I don't know it doesn't throw an error) while extracting.
Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Bind your `error` and `finish`  event handlers to `unzipPipe` and try again.

Comment: Also, `stream.pipeline()` is a better alternative to `readable.pipe()`, especially when errors occur.

Comment: @Ix1412 are saying `unzipPipe.on('finish')` and `unzipPipe.on('error')`?